# How to wait for async emits in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, vuejs3

I'm triggering a `submit` event from a parent component, which emits an `image data-url` and a `body text` from two child components to the parent:

```
<ImgUploadComponent :triggerEmit="state.submit" @emitImage="getImage"/>
  
<EditorComponent :triggerEmit="state.submit" @emitBody="getBody"/>
```

The image and body are fetched with these functions:

```
const getImage = async (image) => {
    form.image = await image
    // arrives after storeRecord
}

const getBody = async (body) => {
    form.body = await body
    // arrives before storeRecord
}
```

and sent to the database in this function:

```
const storeRecord = async () => {
    state.submit = true
    await getImage
    await getBody
    console.log(form.image) // returns undefined
    form.post('/admin/posts')
}
```

Problem is that the `body` arrives before `form.post` is sent but the `image` arrives after. When I wrote this function, it used to work but now it doesn't and I can't figure out why. How do you do it right?

Comment: getImage and getBody are **functions** - the problem is, you aren't calling those functions - so not sure how the code in them ever runs - oh, wait, I see what you think you can do - no, you can't await a function definition

Comment: @Bravo Vue calls the functions from the `@emit` fields in the `child components`

Comment: The previous comment means that there should have been `getImage()`. It's not solved efficiently with promises, because promises are for one-off actions, while there can be multiple emitted values. Observables suit this data flow more. And basically you don't need neither of them, just `watch` for values in parent component

Comment: yeah, I saw that - and that's fine, but the code in storeRecord is far from fine - still trying to figure out what you're doing though - the phrase *triggering a submit event from a parent component, which emits x and y from two child components* sounds like you're doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Estus' suggestion, I was able to use a `watcher` to solve my problem:

```
const storeRecord = () => {
    state.submit = true
    watch(() => form.image, () => {
        form.post('/admin/kreationen')
    })
}

const getImage = (image) => {
    form.image = image
}

const getBody = (body) => {
    form.body = body
}
```